InteractiveViewer in RTL direction
I am creating a Flutter widget that takes text direction as a property. The widget consists of Container widgets wrapped in a Row widget, and this row is wrapped in the InteractiveViewer widget. If the text direction is changed to rtl, the widgets in the Row are laid out as expected from right to left, but the origin of the InteractiveViewer widget is at the top left position of the widget.
A simple code snippet to replicate.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const TestPage(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        )),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('LTR'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const TestPage(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        )),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('RTL'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({required this.textDirection, super.key});

  final TextDirection textDirection;

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  late TextDirection _textDirection;
  final TransformationController _transformationController =
      TransformationController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textDirection = widget.textDirection;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              _textDirection == TextDirection.ltr
                  ? Icons.arrow_back
                  : Icons.arrow_forward,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _textDirection = _textDirection == TextDirection.ltr
                    ? TextDirection.rtl
                    : TextDirection.ltr;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(_textDirection.toString()),
          OffsetWidget(transformationController: _transformationController),
        ],
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Directionality(
            textDirection: _textDirection,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: _transformationController,
              constrained: false,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OffsetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OffsetWidget({required this.transformationController, super.key});

  final TransformationController transformationController;

  @override
  State<OffsetWidget> createState() => _OffsetWidgetState();
}

class _OffsetWidgetState extends State<OffsetWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.transformationController.addListener(_update);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.transformationController.removeListener(_update);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _update() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Offset offset = widget.transformationController.toScene(Offset.zero);
    return Material(
      child: Text(offset.toString()),
    );
  }
}

What have I tried?
I tried copying the InteractiveViewer's code and wrapped the _InteractiveViewerBuilt widget with Directionality widget. Still, the origin is in the top left position.
How can I achieve the InteractiveViewer's origin to be at the top right position if the TextDirection.rtl is set?
